# How to create object from another without undefined properties

Tags: javascript

Is there a better way to accomplish this in Javascript?

```
const data: any = {};
if (values.email) data.email = values.email;
if (values.password) data.password = values.password;
if (values.username) data.username = values.username;
```

I don't want the `data` object to have the properties for the `undefined` or falsy values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could put the potential properties in an array and then [`.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) out any which `values[prop]` has a fasly value for. Then you can [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) each key to an array of `[key, value]` pairs, and use [`Object.fromEntries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) to build the `data` object for you:

```js
const values = {
  email: 'abc',
  username: 'xyz'
};

const props = ['email', 'password', 'username'];
const data = Object.fromEntries(
  props.filter(prop => values[prop]).map(prop => [prop, values[prop]])
);

console.log(data);
```

If you can't support Object.fromEntries(), you could consider using [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign), and then mapping to an array of objects which you then spread into Object.assign():

```js
const values = {
  email: 'abc',
  username: 'xyz'
};

const props = ['email', 'password', 'username'];
const data = Object.assign({},
  ...props.filter(prop => values[prop]).map(prop => ({[prop]: values[prop]}))
);

console.log(data);
```

Comment: I would expect that too many of the environments which don't support `Object.fromEntries` would also not support spreading in an object initializer.  In that case, I would choose a fallback using `reduce` as in the answer from *theDude*.

Comment: @ScottSauyet the second snippet should be es6 compatible, as it is using the spread syntax to spread the _arguments_ into the assign method (rather than the es2018 feature of spreading into an object literal).

Comment: Yes, I misread.  That should be supported in all ES6 environments.

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping that there would be a javascript function or this in ES6. Guess not.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something along these lines:

```js
const obj1 = {
  prop1: true,
  prop2: false,
  prop3: 4,
}

const obj2 =  Object.entries(obj1).reduce((result, [key, value]) => {
  if (value) {
    result[key] = value
  }
  return result
}, {})

console.log(obj2)
```

Answer (score 0):

This simple function will do it, if you want to copy over all properties that don't have a false-y value.  If you only want a fixed list, look at the answer from Nick Parsons.

```js
const copyNonNil = (obj) => 
  Object .fromEntries (Object .entries (obj) .filter(([k, v]) => v))

const values = {
  email: 'foo@bar.baz',
  username: 'foobar',
  password: '',
  another: false
}

console .log (copyNonNil (values))
```

It's easy to shim `Object .fromEntries` if you don't have it available.  See the answer from theDude, which uses a `reduce` that serves in the same role.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) to iterate over the properties of `values` and perform the true/false check in that to make this more flexible:

```
for(const [key, value] of Object.entries(values)){
    if(values[key]) data[key] = value;
}
```

This would give you only the truthy values in `data` for a `values` object of any size.